# Dragging a window by its components using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tidesdk

I have developed a Windows application using TideSDK with HTML , CSS and Javascript.To give it a widget look I disappered its title bar.So I can't drag it.The TideSDK documentation says "after disappearing title bars, you can drag window using its contents with javascript".

How can I drag the window with javascript selecting its components(tiles in my case)?Any tutorial or code as I found nothing on google with my search.

My App looks like below: [image]

Answer (score 2):

I've written the following generic function for dragging using JS:

```
function setDragOfElementOnAnother ($draggableElement, $draggedElememnt, allowDragPredicate) {
    var stopDragFunction = function() {

        $draggedElememnt.data("drag", false);
        $draggedElememnt.removeData("startPoint");

        $("html, body").unbind("mouseup.drag");
        $("html, body").unbind("mousemove.drag");
    };
    var dragFunction = function(e) {
        if (!parseBoolean($draggedElememnt.data("drag")))
            return;

        var begin = $draggedElememnt.data("startPoint");

        $draggedElememnt.css({ left: e.clientX - begin.x, top: e.clientY - begin.y     });
    };

    $draggableElement.mousedown(function(e) {

        if ((e.clientX - $(this).offset().left < 0 || $(this).offset().left +     $(this).width() < e.clientX) ||
            e.clientY - $(this).offset().top < 0)
            return;

        if (allowDragPredicate && !allowDragPredicate(e))
            return;

        $draggedElememnt.data("drag", true);
        $draggedElememnt.data("startPoint", Point(e.clientX - $(this).offset().left, e.clientY - $(this).offset().top));

        $("html, body").bind("mouseup.drag", stopDragFunction);
        $("html, body").bind("mousemove.drag", dragFunction);
    });

    $draggableElement.mouseup(stopDragFunction);
    $draggableElement.mousemove(dragFunction);

}
```

This function is used to declare dragging of one element using another.
**Prerequisites:** 
**(1)** The dragged element's position has to be either fixed or absolute (relative *should* also work).  **(2)** jQuery.

By specifying both dragged and draggable elements as the same one, pressing on the element and moving the mouse will cause the element to drag.

The 'allowDragPredicate' variable is optional, and is useful to create boundaries.

**EDIT:** Forgot. Also add the code:

```
function Point(xVal, yVal) {

    if (xVal === undefined) {
        xVal = 0;
    }
    if (yVal === undefined) {
        yVal = 0;
    }
    return {
        x: xVal,
        y: yVal
    };
}
```

**EDIT 2:** And:

```
function parseBoolean(str) {
    if (str === true)
        return true;
    if (str)
        return /^true$/i.test(str);
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT 3:** And, added a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/BuWdA/) example.

Comment: @I tried it but maybe I am wrong somewhere,please tell me where I am leaving.I included jquery,copied your code inside script tags and as parameters i passed `(elem,elem,allowPredicate(left intact))` where `elem` is created as `var elem=document.getElementById("draggingDiv")`.

Comment: When will the function called?Do I have have to specify an event?

Comment: Call the function with ($(elem),$(elem),allowPredicate(left intact)). The events are registered inside the function, so just call it upon initialization

Comment: Furthermore, I'd suggest you'd get acquainted with jQuery, though it's a wonderful way to work with JS for GUI purposes. For instance, instead of using document.getElementById("draggingDiv"), you can use $("#draggingDiv")

Comment: :I called the function from a div as `onclick='setDragOfElementOnAnother ($("#draggingDiv"), $("#draggingDiv"), allowDragPredicate)'` but its not working.Can you please help.

Comment: Call this function on the 'load' event of the body, or use `$(document).ready(function () {      });`

Comment: Also, forgot to declare another function - Added above